# How to use file.swift into a swift created app(project)?

Tags: swift

I have a task to create an app that checks if a String is a palindrome or not. And also I have instructed to create a file and in that file should be a function. But what I can't figure out is how to make a button run that function that is in the file.

```
func isPalidrone(phrase: String) -> Bool {
    let isPalidrone = true
    let reversed = String(phrase.reversed())

    if reversed == phrase {
        return isPalidrone
    } else {
        return !isPalidrone
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldOutlet: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you put the function into the ViewController class, so it becomes a method of the ViewController class. Also you can reduce the body of your `isPalidrone(phrase: String) -> Bool` function to `return phrase == String(phrase.reversed())`. Just some observations.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let pal = isPalidrone(phrase: self.textFieldOutlet.text!)
    // now pal is true or false and you can decide what else to do ...
    // for example:
    self.Label.text = pal ? "It is a palindrome" : "It is not a palindrome"
}
```